# Multiple actions with one button javafx in clean way

Tags: java, events, button, javafx, action

I am wondering if there is a way to use single JavaFX `Button` and perform different actions on this single `Button` depending on some another condition (example: perform action one when clicked if option one was chosen, action two when option two etc.) in clean way.

I could make it with if statements, that is obvious, but I would prefer some decent and clean way to do that.

Could you suggest me some ideas in orded to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Associate the handler to the option. You could do e.g. this using a `Map<Option, EventHandler<ActionEvent>>` or by simply by implementing functionality in the options themself.

The following example lets the user choose between closing printing `Hello World` to the console or closing the application in a `ComboBox`:

```
// handler with a given return value for toString()
public abstract class NamedEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private final String name;

    public NamedEventHandler(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

```
ComboBox<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new NamedEventHandler("Print \"Hello World\"") {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
        }, new NamedEventHandler("Close") {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Platform.exit();
            }
        }
));

Button button = new Button("OK");
button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = comboBox.getValue();
    if(handler != null) {
        handler.handle(event);
    }
});
```

Using a `Map map` to store the event handlers, you'd use

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = map.get(comboBox.getValue());
```

instead of

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = comboBox.getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will try also with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use a map of methods, something like that:

```
Map<String, Method> actions = new HashMap();
```

Then, get the methods ready to be called:

```
Method method1 = classInstance.getClass().getMethod("myMethodOne")
Method method2 = classInstance.getClass().getMethod("myMethodTwo")
...
```

and populate the map with the methods and their names:

```
actions.put("methodOne", method1);
actions.put("methodTwo", method2);
```

So based on the text entered in a TextField (or anything) you could invoke the desired method, something like:

```
String nameMethodToInvoke = myTextField.getText();
Method methodToInvoke = actions.get(nameMethodToInvoke);
methodToInvoke.invoke()
```

Comment: That could be some way, I will give it a try!